# If $A$ a commutative ring has identity element then $ ann(A)=\{0\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $A$ a commutative ring has identity element then $ ann(A)=\{0\}$

Why is the identity element necessary? Since $a\cdot 0=0$ for all $a\in A$.

And how can I prove that $ann(\emptyset)=A$? Every element of $A$ product with no element is zero?

Comment: If $A$ is a trivial ring (that is, $ab=0$ for all $a,b\in A$), then $\operatorname{ann}(A)=A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ring doesn't have an identity element, then the annihilator of $A$ may be a *larger* set than $\{0\}$ -- consider for example the ring $\{0,2\}$ with multiplication and addition modulo 4, in which everything annihilates everything!

Comment: Thak you! Can you give me a hint about $ann(\emptyset)=A$?